# Elasticsearch change internal timezone

Tags: elasticsearch

i have a Elasticsearch cluster for storing logz, and my current timezone is+06, but Elasticsearch work in UTC +0, so how can i change the timezone in Elasticsearch cluster?

Answer (score 1):

[ES stores date-times in (UTC)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html#_time_zone_2) and there's no cluster-/index-wide setting to change that.

With that being said, the `time_zone` parameter in available in both [(range) queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#range-query-time-zone) and [aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html#_time_zone_2).

Also, as you index your date fields, there are [(date)time formats](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html#built-in-date-formats) that do support time zones. You can also use the [date processor pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/date-processor.html#date-processor) to append a certain time zone if your fields don't include one already.